# Drupal 7 theme similar to Wordpress Twenty Fourteen theme?

Tags: theming

I'm looking for a Drupal 7 theme similar to the wordpress theme [Twenty Fourteen](http://wordpress.org/themes/twentyfourteen). The main factors that I would like to find in a drupal theme are

- the image grid for posts similar to the grid pictured on the theme page
- the menu locked into the side
- responsive

I was hoping to find something with as little modification needed as possible, but I'm not opposed to creating a subtheme and doing some customization. I tried searching some drupal theme repositories like the offerings available on themeforest and template monster but I haven't found anything that caught my eye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to find Drupal is pretty limited on well made pre-built themes. If you're looking for a good grid system, [NineSixty](https://drupal.org/project/ninesixty) and [Boostrap](https://drupal.org/project/bootstrap) provide a good base to build upon. As far as menu settings and post output, this is typically custom to each site. The post output, for instance, would rely on a custom content type and View to display this information.